# Scrape text from H tag from web page and save it to csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I ma trying to extract text from all h3 and h4 tags from page and save it to csv file:

Sample:

```
<div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">

    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h4>service text</h4>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h3 style="color: #2ac4ea; font-size: 35px;">2.900</h3>

        </div>
    </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
```

My code:

```
service=[]
price=[]

url = 'www.site.com'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.content, 'html.parser')



for div in soup.findAll(class_='row'):
    for div1 in div.findAll(class_='vc_column-inner'):

            services=div1.find('h4')
            prices=div1.find('h3')
            service.append(services)
            price.append(prices)


df = pd.DataFrame({'service':service,'price':price}) 
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Results:

```
service,price
<h4>service text</h4>,"<h3 style=""color: #2ac4ea; font-size: 35px;"">2.900</h3>"
```

I need to be like this:

```
service,price
service text,2.900
```

Is this possible with above method?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you append `services` and `prices` variables to lists, use `.get_text()` method:

```
service.append(services.get_text(strip=True))
price.append(prices.get_text(strip=True))
```

Then the result will be:

```
service,price
service text,2.900
```

---

The code:

```
service=[]
price=[]

url = 'www.site.com'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.content, 'html.parser')



for div in soup.findAll(class_='row'):
    for div1 in div.findAll(class_='vc_column-inner'):

            services=div1.find('h4')
            prices=div1.find('h3')
            service.append(services.get_text(strip=True))  # <-- .get_text()
            price.append(prices.get_text(strip=True))      # <-- .get_text()

df = pd.DataFrame({'service':service,'price':price}) 
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but when i use .get_text() i get the following error:

service.append(services.get_text(strip=True))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'